# sceneWillEnterForeground called when app terminates

Tags: swift, uiscenedelegate, ios-lifecycle

I'm updating a Firebase database variable in `sceneWillEnterForeground`, and for some reason it the update gets triggered not only when the app goes to foreground, but also when I quit the app, It doesn't get triggered when I go to background. How is this possible?

I'm 100% sure it's `sceneWillEnterForeground` that's causing the Firebase database to update, I'm not calling the update from anywhere else in the code.

Comment: You should be saving when the app goes into the _background_, not the foreground.

Comment: Also what does "quit the app" even mean? You can't quit an iOS app.